# Find the specific hash that contains the specific values from the array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Hi I have a array of hashes as follows,

```
[{"rel"=>"self", "uri"=>"/organizations;start=100;count=100"},
 {"rel"=>"nextPage", "uri"=>"/organizations;start=200;count=100"},
 {"rel"=>"previousPage", "uri"=>"/organizations;start=0;count=100"}]
```

now I have to find the nextPage uri link. So can I achieve this.

Comment: think, try, show the code if your approach not working

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error are you seeing?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data.find { |a| a['rel'] == 'nextPage' }['uri']
```

Comment: `select { ... }.first` can be expressed as `find { ... }`

Comment: @ Stefan Thanks. I've made that change :)

Comment: You might also want to specify a default value if there's no such element to prevent a `NoMethodError` (`nil['uri']` doesn't work)